# ReactJS Horizontal-Timeline Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component  [Component (codesandbox.io)](https://codesandbox.io/s/0oooxvx7ll)   and i´m trying to pass

const Example which is an example of the data structure i´m passing to the component.

```js
const EXAMPLE = [
  {data: '2018-03-22', status: 'status', statusB: 'Ready for Dev', StatusE: 'In Progress'},
  {data: '2018-03-23', status: 'status', statusB: 'In Progress', statusE: 'Done'},
]
```

I could make a new array with the Data property only, but i also need 
`{statusB} -> {StatusE}` as you can see on the image below

This is what i´m trying to achieve:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map your `data` inside the `EXAMPLE`  array, like [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2v37vw5zpp)

`values={EXAMPLE.map(x => x.data)}`

Comment: Hello @Firice Nguyen, but how do i place `{statusB} -> {StatusE}`  instead `{this.state.value}` like in the image..? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: if you select a date, it will show below 0, 1, 2 etc which is `{this.state.value}` but instead i want to show `{statusB} -> {StatusE}` you can see on the image i´ve uploaded there is `Ready for Dev -> In Progress` which is the statusB -> StatusE for `Mar 22 2018`

Comment: @ Firice Nguyen Thanks! Its working, i´ve been trying to find out why the correct values `{statusB} -> {StatusE}` only appear after the 2nd click! Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @zemmsoares It depends on your application logic. You can see this line in the code: `{curStatus} - {prevStatus}`. In the codesandbox, I retrieve `statusB` of different object, if you want `{statusB} -> {StatusE}` then just change it. Please notice that your `statusB` using downcase `s` and the `StatusC` using upcase `S`. It could lead to some error